How to Create Drop Down List with Multiple Selections?
I have an Excel document with five sheets. On the second sheet there are three codes under Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range) that goes like this :
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling one-cell changes
    
    DoMessage Target
    HideShowRows Target
    DropDown Target
    
End Sub

The DoMessage Target and HideShowRows are good, they work perfectly. DropDown target doesn't work. This code is supposed to allow several items in a dropdown list to be chosen by the user simultaneously and non-repetitively. Here's the code for this one :
Sub DropDown(Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H11")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
            Else:
                Target.Value = Oldvalue
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

What's wrong with the code ?

What does it do instead of work?  Application.EnableEents = False seems like a typo?  Try commenting out the error handler and see if there are errors you're not seeing.

Nothing, if I choose an item in H11 cell, I cannot put another in it. It will just change the item.

Apparently there is an error to Application.Undo but I don't understand it.

What's the error# and text? I think the error is caused by the typo which is mentioned in @TimWilliams comment.

"Run-time Error 1004" : The method of 'Undo' in the object '_Application' failed.

I would maybe put DropDown Target first, to make sure the other calls aren't affecting the Undo.
Try this instead: it should handle both additions and removals when a value is selected from the list..
Sub DropDown(Target As Range)
    Const SEP As String = vbNewLine
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String, arr, el, s As String, removing As Boolean
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H11")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            If Len(Newvalue) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing to do...
            
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                arr = Split(Oldvalue, SEP) 'split if multiple values
                For Each el In arr         'loop over previous selection(s) and compare to new value
                    If el <> Newvalue Then
                        s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "") & el
                    Else
                        removing = True    'previous selection was re-selected
                    End If
                Next el
                If Not removing Then s = s & SEP & Newvalue
                Target.Value = s
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Exitsub:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Unfortunately, this code does not work either.

Works fine for me.  You'll need to step through and see what's going wrong.  See also my note at the top about calling this code first before  DoMessage and HideShowRows
